# Closed subsets in metric space

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

I want to prove that any closed subset $F$ from a metric space $(E,d)$ can be written as a denumerable  intersection of open sets i.e.,

$$F=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \Theta_n; \Theta_n=\bigcup_{x\in F} B(x,\frac{1}{n})$$

It is clear that $F\subset \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \Theta_n$

I suppose that $y\in \Theta_n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}^*$ and $y\notin F$ i.e., $\exists \delta>0; B(y,\delta)\cap F\neq \emptyset$ but the fact $y\in \Theta_n$ means that there exist $x\in F$ such that $d(x,y)<\frac1n, \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ it still right for $n$ such that $\frac1n<\delta$ and then $x\in F\cap B(y,\delta)$ contradiction.

But I don't know where to use the fact that $F$ is closed and $\Theta_n$ is open?

Thank you.

Comment: You should have $B(y,\delta)\cap F=\emptyset$ (otherwise no contradiction would be found); this is possible *because* $F$ is closed and $y\notin F$. The fact that $\Theta_n$ is open is a consequence of its definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $y\in\Theta_n$, for all $n$ and $y\notin F$.

**Since $F$ is closed**, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $B(y,\delta)\cap F=\emptyset$.

Consider $n$ such that $1/n<\delta$. Since $y\in\Theta_n$, there is $x\in F$ such that $y\in B(x,1/n)$ (by definition of $\Theta_n$).

Then $d(x,y)<1/n<\delta$, so $x\in B(y,\delta)$. Since $x\in F$, we have $x\in B(y,\delta)\cap F$, so $B(y,\delta)\cap F\ne\emptyset$.

Contradiction.

Therefore such a $y$ must belong to $F$ and we have proved that
$$
F=\bigcap_{n>0}\Theta_n
$$

Since $\Theta_n$ is **open** by construction (a union of open spheres), it follows that every closed set in a metric space is a countable intersection of open sets (a $G_\delta$, in a common terminology).

---

### Addition

An alternative way of proving that, if $y\in\Theta_n$ for all $n$, then $y\in F$ is as follows.

Let $n>0$; then $y\in \Theta_n$, so $y\in B(x_n,1/n)$, for some $x_n\in F$. Let's see that the sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $y$.

Fix $\varepsilon>0$ and take $n$ such that $n>1/\varepsilon$. Then
$$
d(x_n,y)<1/n<\varepsilon
$$
Thus, taking $\bar{n}>1/\varepsilon$, we see that, for every $n\ge \bar{n}$, we have $d(x_n,y)<\varepsilon$, which amounts to our thesis.

Since $F$ is closed and $y$ is the limit of a sequence in $F$, then $y\in F$.

**Note.** This is essentially the same as the proof by contradiction above. It's neither more nor less correct.

Comment: Pedantic terminological correction: "open balls", not "open spheres"

Comment: @MPW They are called spheres, balls and also disks.

Comment: I accept "disk", but definitely not "sphere". A sphere is a compact set that is the boundary of a ball. There is no such thing as an open sphere. That said, you can always define a term to mean whatever you wish. But that isn't conventional usage.

Comment: @MPW *You* call *sphere* the boundary; others don't. If you want to edit, you're welcome.

Comment: but please why exactly $F$ closed implise the exstence of $\delta$ ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou Any point $y\notin F$ is not in the closure of $F$ (because $F$ is already closed).

Comment: ah so if $F$ where not closed the if $y\notin F$ then $y$ can be in $\overline{F}$ right ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou Yes, exactly so. Now do you see where the fact that $F$ is closed is used?

Comment: yes thank you and happy new year

Comment: @egreg: It's your call to edit or not, just mentioning it. No worries, not a big deal really.

Comment: @egreg i obtained 0 no one told me that $\exists x_n\in F$ and not $\exists x\in F$

Comment: @Vrouvrou Since the variable after $\exists$ is a bound one, it's ***completely irrelevant*** how it's called, so long as the name isn't used in the same argument with another meaning. Grading as wrong the argument for this is ***very*** surprising.

Comment: @egreg he says that we must take a sequence $(x_n)$ i don't realy understand how to continu but form it is false

Comment: @Vrouvrou Sorry; but it reminds me a kid who had been my pupil and came to ask me whether his solution to a problem was correct. I told him it was, he replied that his new teacher said it was wrong. I couldn't say anything else than “sorry, next time do as she wants”. Grading as wrong  a correct proof just because it uses a different path than what one prefers is arrogant and stupid.

Comment: but i want to understand it's proof whene i say there exists a sequense $x_n$ for him $d(x_n,y)<\frac1n$ means that $x_n$ converge to y what happen after that ? please

Comment: @Vrouvrou As I said, I think it's foolish grading as wrong an argument because it's different from the way I'd do it. Complain, but be sure your argument is fully correct. If it's the same as the one I presented, it *is* correct (but beware of possible bad translation). I added, anyway, the proof with sequences.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For every subset $S$  define $$d(x,S)=\inf\{d(x,s):s\in S\} $$ which is a continous function on $E$

and try to show that $$F=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \theta_n$$ where $$\theta_n =\{x\in E : d(x,F)<\frac{1}{n} \}$$

because of continuity $\theta_n$ is open for every $n\in \mathbb N$